# Android App Code Retrieve

Tags: java, android, android-applicationinfo

Why are there errors keep showing in cmd when I try to retrieve my java code from the created android .apk file?? Whenever I try to use cmd to go to C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\dex2jar-0.0.9.15>dex2jar classes.dex, after hitting enter, there comes this message : " 'java' is not recognized as an interval or external command, operatable program or batch file." Why is this happening? I unzipped jd-gui-0.3.6.windows as well as dex2jar-0.0.9.15 file!!

Answer (score 1):

That means that the computer does not recognize java as a command. Are you sure you have set the environment variable leading to the bin of the jdk directory?

Comment: It worked now! Just updated the previous PATH Environment Variable. Don't know the exact reason but probably bcz of updating to the newer version of JDK. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Anytime! I'm glad I could be of use.